# Can one set up an if-statement to search for a certain pattern in a text file?

Tags: java, algorithm, if-statement, text-files, fractions

I am working on a project in java that has to do with fractions. Now in this project, I have to take a list of fractions out of a text file and depending on there line i have to simplify, add, subtract, multiply, and divide them. 
Part of text file:

```
-16/6
-7/2
-17
+20 4/2 / +8 4/8
-17/15 + +14/17
+17 5/14 + -2
```

Now my question is, is there a way to set up an if statement or something to look for "anynumber_/_anynumber" or "anynumber_anynumber/anynumber" when I pull a line out of the text file and read it.

If not, what would be the best way to cut the fractions out?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code yet? If so, post the relevant part here.

Comment: Look up the `String#split` method or regular expressions.

Comment: you can use this regEx for matching your pattern [-+\d\/]+

Comment: Thank you so much, it works great now. Basically all i do is just search for the patterns and then do the math. Again thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `StringTokenizer` class. Im using your example here.

```
String nextLine = "-17/15 + +14/17";      //you read in each line as a String
String delimiters = "+-*/ ";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(nextLine, delimiters, true);

    while(st.hasMoreElements()){
    System.out.println(st.nextElement());
    }
```

It will divide into [ - , 17 , / , 15 , , + , , + , 14 , / , 17 ] , this `while` loop prints them all out so you can see how the tokenizer works.
Then you can put all the operands and operators on stacks and add logic to evaluate them accordingly from there. You should give more details about your project if you are asking for a specific method. Its a little unclear on what you want to do. It seems like you want to create a expression evaluator program but then you also state that you want to have a program that searches a file for division expressions.

you can look at each token

```
if(st.nextElement.equals("+"));
if(st.nextElement.equals("-"));
if(st.nextElement.equals("/"));
if(st.nextElement.equals("*"));
if(st.nextElement.equals(" "));   //whitespace
else;                             //else it is a number
```

Comment: Thank you, you have been very helpful. Its works 100%.